# Row with 4 span3 - when span3 wrapped in <a> tags causes last span3 to wrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with 4 span 3's in - I want to use as navigation:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">Home</div>
    <div class="span3">About</div>
    <div class="span3">Our Stuff</div>
    <div class="span3">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

This displays & resizes responsively fine.
[image]

If I wrap the `div`s in `a` tags - the last span3 becomes misaligned - even though the developer tools show the same widths:
[image]

How can I wrap the `div`'s in `a` tags whilst keeping them aligned?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot wrap a `div` with an anchor (`a`)

This should be the solution:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
    <div class="span3"><a href="#">About</a></div>
    <div class="span3"><a href="#">Our Stuff</a></div>
    <div class="span3"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#"><span class="span3">Home</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="span3">About</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="span3">Our Stuff</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span class="span3">Contact Us</span></a>
</div>
```

PS:

It's always useful to show who wants to help some [sample](http://bootply.com/81455) code. 
This [tool](http://bootply.com/) might help you. Another one can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: thanks - problem with that is only the text is then clickable - i would like the whole DIV to be clickable as this is a navigation bar.

Comment: I have re-asked this question here - sorry don't think I stated the problem very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855954/responsive-twitter-bootstrap-best-practice-create-4-navigation-buttons-below