# Responsive Twitter Bootstrap, Best Practice - Create 4 Navigation buttons below logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like 4 navigation buttons to take up the full width, with a column gap between each (as if they were 4 span3 DIVS).

Like this:
[image]

This doesn't fit any of the Bootstrap navigation examples I can find - they are all stuck to the top.

Bearing in mind navigation should be an unordered list - how can I best implement this, keeping it responsive?

UPDATE 19 Sep 2013 - JSFiddle image below: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt bootstrap's navbar (below example is bootstrap 2.3.2), making it look more like yours, but still keeping their responsive styling.  Don't forget when using navbar to include jquery and bootstrap.js on your page or the menu button when viewing on mobile won't work.

```
<style>
    .navbar-inner {
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .nav li {
        background: #ccc;
        text-align: center;
    }
    @media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) {
        .navbar [class*="span"], .navbar .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
            float: none;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    }

</style>

<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav row-fluid">
                    <li class="span3"><a href="#">Home</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="span3"><a href="#">About Us</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="span3"><a href="#">Our Stuff</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="span3"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guydog28/7Aguy/), resize the width of the results window to see desktop vs mobile navbar.

**UPDATE**

If you wish to do this without the navbar component (and thus losing the tablet/mobile dropdown but staying responsive), a simple nav should do.  Try this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/guydog28/CY2Bv/).  Code Below:

```
<style>    
    .custom-nav .nav li a {
        background-color: #aaa;
        text-align: center;
        color : white;
        padding: 6px 0;
    }
    .custom-nav .nav li a:hover,
    .custom-nav .nav li a:hover{
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .custom-nav .nav li {
            margin-bottom:2px;
        }
    }    
</style>

<div class="custom-nav">
    <ul class="nav row-fluid">
        <li class="span3"><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li class="span3"><a href="#">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li class="span3"><a href="#">Our Stuff</a>

        </li>
        <li class="span3"><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - works really well. I do need a logo / white space above it. Is that easy to add?

Comment: also in the jsfiddle - they never display like mine - just with the mobile burger menu. If that is stretched wide they stop taking up the full width and misalign on the left?! (tried on FF & Chrome Windows). The burger never disappears

Comment: As for the whitespace, all you need to do is add another div above the navbar, and put what you need in it.  Something like <div class="container-fluid"><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span3" id="logo">(logo here)</div><div class="span9><span class="pull-right">(right justified header stuff)</span></div></div></div>.  Also, you may want to consider putting all of this and your site content in a <div class="container"> to give a basis point for all your content.

Comment: Also, my examples are using *-fluid, which is the percentage based grid in bootstrap.  If you are looking for fixed grid, drop the *-fluids.  See http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html for the differences between Grid System and Fluid Grid System.

Comment: Thanks - do you know why it isn't displaying properly when wide in jsfiddle? (I have added image to question).

Comment: Well that is the view for tablets.  The thing with the navbar out of the box is that for tablets AND phones it goes to menu mode, however the li's in the menu don't go to max width until phone size, leaving tablet size looking a little funky.  I added a media query to the jsfiddle to override the look of span3's for the navbar only when in tablet size.  I also added a little help div/js to show you the current width of the frame so you know what device you are simulating as you resize.  If this answers your question, feel free to hit the checkmark and mark this as your answer :)

Comment: thanks. At width 948 it is still showing the menu button. At this width it should show the buttons all the time, horizontally, as in my original screen grab. Do you know why that is? It should only show the menu burger button on mobile (say below 480?). Thanks

Comment: Are you using bootstrap LESS or CSS?  If LESS, you need to change in `variables.less` that variable `@navbarCollapseWidth` to be 480.  However between 979 and 480 you'll likely have to make other changes to how li are display as they stack well before 480 as well.  If you are using their css, the 480 thing will be far more difficult.

Comment: Not using LESS, just standard CSS & bootstrap. Shouldn't it just work?

Comment: Well that's just thing, it does 'just work' the way bootstrap intended it to.  They saw tablet size as needing the dropdown menu, so that is how their CSS is setup to do it (collapse at 979 into drop down menu).  When you use their less code, that threshold is set in a variable that you can easily edit and it will change it everywhere in the CSS.  If you are using CSS, you will need to modify their CSS files.  Find `@media (max-width: 979px)` in `bootstrap-responsive.css` and change the width to 480.  Then find `@media (min-width: 980px)` and change to 481.

Comment: hmm OK thanks - Ideally I don't want to change bootstrap files (incase I update etc). Seems rolling my own may be better?!... I'm not a huge fan of the burger menu anyway

Comment: OK I added a new fiddle since you don't like the burger menu, this should be simpler and do the trick for you.

Comment: awesome! One minor question, the rollover doesn't cover the full height of the button, easy fix?

Comment: All should be fixed.  I scoped the styles inside a custom div so it would affect any other nav elements you have on the page, and fixed the hovers.  Code is now included in answer above and the fiddle is updated with that code.  If this satisfies you solution, feel free to upvote/accept the answer above!